# Por que el archivo .htaccess me modifica la url?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tego un archivo .htaccess con la siguiente configuración:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


#prevenir acceso al archivo .htaccess
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?views=$1 [L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?views=$1&metodo=$2 [L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ ?views=$1&metodo=$2&parametros=$3 [L]
```

La cuestión es que cuando paso en la url del navegador parámetros como  ***wpOgiLG5cJ%2BFr42HmqiloaSmZ6empaCVvWWUl4C2gXSVppKWm6%2BAjZyml56km7M%3D*** me lo convierte  en una url como esta ***wpOgiLG5cJ Fr42HmqiloaSmZ6empaCVvWWUl4C2gXSVppKWm6 AjZyml56km7M=*** lo cual me genera error al tratar de procesar la url.
¿alguna razón para que pase esto?

Comment: comparto la url que me esta dando problemas para ampliar el caso "http://localhost/tramites/trazabilidad/SolicitudRegistro/Consultar/wpOgiLG5cJ%2BFr42HmqiloaSmZ6empaCVvWWUl4C2gXSVppKWm6%2BAjZyml56km7M%3D", teniendo en cuenta que el archivo .htaccess se encuentra ubicado en la carpeta trazabilidad

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tiene que ver con
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ ?views=$1&metodo=$2&parametros=$3 [L]
te lo convierte en parametro
si lo comentas y volver a probar

Comment: Gracias Raphael por tu comentario, la cuestión es que si cometo este pedazo el programa esperara la varirable $_GET["parametros"] la cual no se encontrara. 

Comment: ah pero viste que esa linea al pasar por esa regla saca los parametros, y deja vacio el enlace o sea queda en blanco, no te conviene mandalos normal asi no tenes que usar esa conversion?, o en todo caso tendrias que modificar esa regla para mandarlos como parametro sin tocar el enlace

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucha investigación encontré que *`rewrite_rule`* decodifica los caracteres especiales como por ejemplo `%2F%2B%5C%2A` a estos `/+\*`. En este sentido php interpreta el carácter + (%2B) como un espacio.
la solución esta en agregar el indicador `B` a RewriteRule para que escape a estos caracteres así:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?views=$1 [L,B]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?views=$1&metodo=$2 [L,B]


RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\W]+)/?$ ?views=$1&metodo=$2&parametros=$3 [L,B]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720650/htaccess-url-encoded-string-not-passing-to-page-correctly

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b